# Angular 13 - Support for the experimental syntax 'importMeta' isn't currently enabled

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

After upgrading to angular 13 I'm having this issue. I am trying to create a worker like this:

```
new Worker(new URL('../path/to/worker', import.meta.url), {type: 'module'})
```

This works fine when I do "**ng serve**" or "**ng build**". However, it does not work when I run "**ng build --configuration production**". If I turn **buildOptimizer** and **aot** to false it does work but that's something I'm trying to avoid.

It looks like this has everything to to with the **import.meta.url**. It doesn't make much sense since this is an established standard.

So, when I run "ng build --configuration production" It throws the error:

> Error: Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
>
> SyntaxError: Support for the experimental syntax 'importMeta' isn't
> currently enabled (18:102):
>
> Add @babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta (https://git.io/vbKK6) to the
> 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable parsing.

This is weird since I'm not using babel, at least directly. Maybe it's Angular's buildOptimizer that uses babel, but if it is, I cannot change it's configs.

Is there any fix or workaround to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after upgrading to Angular 12 from 9. I managed to fix the issue by removing the node_modules folder and the package-lock.json file and running npm install.

There must have been some conflicting packages or something but doing the above fixed it.